# Matrix field in user-profile front-end

Tags: users, matrix, user-profile

I created matrix field, put it in the user field. In the front-end page as usually write

```
{% for block in user.myMatrixfield.type('myType') %}
   ................
{% endfor %}
```

but there is no output!
try to write `{% user.myMatrixfield|length %}` - outputs 0

In administration panel everything works.
How to get matrix field in user-profile front-end page?

Comment: How are you setting the user variable? Can you supply the template code for the page?

Comment: way for the user does not need the same variable, the user simply

Answer (score 1):

It works identically to entries.

Here are a couple things you can do to troubleshoot:

- Make sure that `user` is set to the user account you’re expecting it is. You can double check that by outputting `{{ user.username }}`.
- Make sure that you’re calling the right Matrix field handle, with the correct capitalization.
- If you’re passing the `type` param, make sure you’re passing in the right Block Type handle.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry, 
I forgot to put the original values in administration panel. That is, I did not push +myMatrixfield and it turns out that the matrix field does not exist.